# How to select a random number from a super set with different probability of each sub set

Tags: python, random, probability

I need to select a number at random from a set Y of 100 numbers as [1.00 to 2.00) with four subsets of following probability.

1. Y1--> [1.00-1.39)---probability(0.4)
2. Y2--> [1.40-1.69)---probability(0.3)
3. Y1--> [1.70-1.89)---probability(0.2)
4. Y1--> [1.90-1.99)---probability(0.1)

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: start reading the random module - especially [choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) - it accepts propabilities. As is your question is framed far too broad.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yeah i did read that but was getting confused on how to take different sets, anyways got it cleared with the answer I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). The good thing is that you can specify weights

```
import random
def pick_random():
    randoms = [random.uniform(1.0, 1.39), random.uniform(1.4, 1.69), random.uniform(1.7, 1.89), random.uniform(1.9, 1.99)]
    weights = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
    return round(random.choices(randoms, weights=weights)[0], 2)
```